# How to call java script function from ashx handler file

Tags: javascript, c#, ashx

My function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function methodtocall(id) {
  // My code
}
</script>
```

My ashx page

```
public class sampleClass : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
// here i need to call that method
}
}
```

yes i referred net.But no solutions for that. mostly they give solution to call from method to ashx or call from ajax.

can anyone direct me with correct thing?

Comment: Are you expecting to do something with the response of your javascript function in your handler? In what context are you calling the handler?

Answer (score 0):

Refer like this,

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "methodtocall", script, true);
```

as per code,

```
public class sampleClass : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
var id = "someid"; //implement the id that you want to pass to the Javascript function
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "methodtocall", id, true);
}
}
```

Hope this helps..!

reference Link : [Link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-JavaScript-function-from-Code-Behind-without-using-ScriptManager-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Comment: Just note, handlers are quite different from a web form page. We know nothing about the context in which this handler is called. However, it does seem to return plain text **not** HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>function closeCurrentTab(){var conf=confirm('Are you sure, you want to close this tab?');if(conf==true){close();}}</script>");

context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>closeCurrentTab();</script>");
```